# Joomla - How to tell what {{ }} links to?

Tags: php, joomla

I've been tasked with updating a page on our Joomla-powered website. Finding the page is easy enough from the contents area, but the two sections I need to edit are not on the page. Instead I find two markers: {{2}} and {{3}}. My assumption are these are placeholders for modules, but I can't for the life of me find any modules that contain the content I need to edit.

Is there a way to figure out what these place holders point to?

Joomla version is 2.5.

Comment: Most modules are called in articles by single brackets not double.  If it's not in module manager, did you check the plugins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The curly brackets {} are typical of a [Joomla Content plugin](https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/Content), however, normally there is more inside the brackets which can give clues to what the plugin is.

If these tags are in an Article, then I would hazard a guess that a Content plugin using `onContentPrepare` is processing the article body and replacing their contents. The first step will be identifying the plugin, which in turn may lead to a component (under the `Components` menu).

If that doesn't help — as this question is about Joomla specific implementation details, you may get a better result if you, try asking on [the Joomla Q&A StackExhange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Comment: There is a Joomla-dedicated SE page ? :) Damn, this networks seriously takes over the dev world!

Comment: Thanks for this! You were correct. In this case the Content Plugin proved to be Content - JIncludes, where the number in the brackets corresponds to a numbered code snippet in the plugins configuration.